# How to input Unicode character in Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicode, console

While using Rails console, when I input `ä`, `\U+FFC3\U+FFA4` appears.
 Of course I can input Unicode characters outside of rails.

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0p247, Rails 4.0.0 in Max OS X 10.7.5.

How can I input Unicode characters in Rails console?

Comment: Thanks, but I can input unicode character in terminal without problem. I can't input only in rails console.

Comment: Do you use rvm? Most likely you've got readline issue, https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1016 or http://blog.rlmflores.me/blog/2012/04/25/adding-utf-8-support-to-rubies-compiled-through-ruby-build/

Comment: I'm using rbenv, but as you said readline was the problem. I reinstall the ruby and works fine now! Could you write it as a answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you've got readline issue, try to re-install Ruby with readline support. https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1016 or http://blog.rlmflores.me/blog/2012/04/25/adding-utf-8-support-to-rubies-compiled-through-ruby-build/

Answer (score 16):

I did have the same problem. After done a lot of things, including the complete reinstall of RVM, I'd realized I just need to define the LC variables. To do the same, run these commands on terminal:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LANG LC_COLLATE LC_CTYPE LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_ALL
```

One good idea is save this code in .bash_profile or .bashrc files in the App folder.

Comment: 3 years after your answer, I was having the same issue. Thank you very much, Fernando, it was really helpful!

Comment: in case of .zshrc it helps too

Comment: Yeah, @okliv. I do think this solution can helps everybody. Just change `en_US.UTF-8` to your right character set.