# Controller I18n encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, rails-i18n

In a Rails controller, I'd like to compute an i18n message to be sent to front-end. I proceed as follow:

```
flash[:notice] = I18n.t 'programs.update.program_saved'
```

In my translation file (fr.yml), the translation is the following one: '**Programme sauvegardé**'.

When setting a breakpoint on this line, and then typing it in my console, I have encoding issues:

```
0> I18n.t 'programs.update.program_saved'
=> "Programme sauvegardÃ©"
```

I have implemented the [AJAX pattern](https://minhajuddin.com/2014/03/12/show-rails-flash-messages-in-jquery-ajax-requests/) to handle flash messages, and on the front side, I can see the same encoding issue.

Apart from that, when I type the same thing in a `rails console`, I have no encoding issue.

I'm in `Ruby 2.4.4` and `Rails 5.2.1`.

What can cause this encoding issue, and how to get rid of it?

**EDIT: Add additional details**

I develop using `RubyMine 2018.2`. My rails server is running under a `WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)` with an `Ubuntu 16`. I run my rails server from RubyMine, from `Windows` side. The `rails SDK` that is used is a `Linux` one. The `rails server` runs on `Linux` side.

The oigin of my problem was encoding issues in my browser, when showing flash messages set in HTTP request response. These flash message are computed as explained, i.e.: `I18n.t 'programs.update.program_saved'`.

The problem is the same when I launch my rails server from my RubyMine, or directly from Linux terminal.

To investigate, I wanted to debug and use the RubyMine console. When executing this command from RubyMine debugger console, there still were encoding issues: `I18n.t 'programs.update.program_saved'`. When doing it from `rails console` in `Linux` or `Windows` (in `RubyMine`, the rails console executes on `Linux` side), I have no encoding issue.

Furthermore, the issue is still present when running the app on a heroku instance, so I'm wondering whether this is related to my local config or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is apparent somewhere down the line your String is interpreted as "ISO-8859-1" despite the fact it actually is "UTF-8".
You can check the fact with the following code snippet in irb or Rails console:

```
s=[0x64,0xc3,0xa9].pack('c*')  # => "d\xC3\xA9" ("dé" if UTF-8)
s.encoding    # => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
s.encode "UTF-8", "UTF-8"      # => "dé"  ("de'")
s.encode "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1" # => "dÃ©" ("d~A(c)")
```

I can think of two possibilities for what went wrong.

### Case 1

Your terminal where Rails console is run is either incapable of interpreting UTF-8 string or wrongly set up.

Try the following code snippet (nb., it can be run by any one, even if the translation is undefined):

```
s2 = I18n.t('programs.update.program_saved', :default => nil)
s2 ||= [0x64,0xc3,0xa9].pack('c*').encode("UTF-8", "UTF-8")  # => "dé"  ("de'")
p s2[-2,2].bytes  # => [100, 195, 169]  if the object is in UTF-8
                  # => [100, 233]       if the object is in ISO-8859-1
```

and you can see how the (internal) encoding of the String object is.
If it is `[100, 195, 169]`, then the encoding is UTF-8, and hence both Ruby and Rails treat the translated String object correctly as UTF-8, and so the problem is in you terminal.  Your terminal wrongly interprets the byte-string `[100, 195, 169]` that it received from Rails as ISO-8859-1 and chooses the characters and font to display accordingly.

In Rails consolei on your terminal, you can try this; it should display the characters correctly if terminal is UTF-8 compatible:

```
[0x64,0xc3,0xa9].pack('c*').force_encoding('UTF-8')
  # => "dé" ("de'") should be displayed.
```

Chack out your terminal is really capable of displaying UTF-8 strings (most modern terminals should be able to, but old ones may not).
Also, check out your terminal settings.  This [answer to "How to input Unicode character in Rails console?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857471/how-to-input-unicode-character-in-rails-console/44556239#44556239) may be of help.

### Case 2

It is Ruby that interpretes the input string as "ISO-8859-1" and internally converted it to "UTF-8" (though it should not happen in the default setting).
In that case, a possibility is your yml file may contain some characters that look like "ISO-8859-1"; then Rails might interpret the entire file as "ISO-8859-1" (though very unlikely).

You can check if the file you read (`config/locales/fr.yml`) is indeed in UTF-8 as follows:

```
fn = 'config/locales/fr.yml'
IO.binread(fn).force_encoding('UTF-8').valid_encoding?  # => should be true
IO.binread(fn).force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').valid_encoding?  # => false
```

Unfortunately there is a bit of flaw.  Some UTF-8 characters can be legitimately interpreted as ISO-8859-1, and in such cases how a code (Rails) interprets it might vary.  If you suspect that is the case, you can look at the output of the above command like `IO.binread(fn).force_encoding('UTF-8')` and see if every character is as expected.

If the file contains some non-UTF-8 characters, fix it, and hopefully everything will be fine.

Or, in your particular case, you can perhaps fix it as a botch job like

```
I18n.t('programs.update.program_saved').encode('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1')
```

### Note

So long as you want to make the Rails defult as UTF-8 (strongly advised), make sure the default encoding of your app is UTF-8.  Check it out via

```
MyApp::Application.config.encoding  # => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

(Reference: [Configuring Rails Applications](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html))

Also, if you are using Heroku, set the default charset to UTF-8.  See the [answer to "Set UTF-8 as default string encoding in Heroku"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612912/set-utf-8-as-default-string-encoding-in-heroku).

---

Note a major update was made on 2018-11-05 to add Case 1.

Comment: `IO.binread(fn).force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').valid_encoding?` returns `true`.`IO.binread(fn).force_encoding('UTF-8').valid_encoding?` returns `true`.
`I18n.t('programs.update.program_saved').encode('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1')` returns `Programme sauvegardÃÂ©`. `I18n.t('programs.update.program_saved').encode('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8')` returns `Programme sauvegardé` as I expect. I recreated my `fr.yml` from scratch, in UTF8, but it didn't changed anything. `MyApp::Application.config.encoding` returns `UTF-8` as expected. It means somethings messes up with encoding `ISO-8859-1`. Haven't found yet.

Comment: @RémiDoolaeghe The problem may be on your terminal, then. I have made a major update on my answer (to add Case 1). Check it out.

Comment: Looks like my debugger console has encoding issues, as `[0x64,0xc3,0xa9].pack('c*').force_encoding('UTF-8')` returns `dÃ©`. My rails console returns `dé`. I provided additional details in my OP. I think the problem is wider than just a console configuration issue, because it happens in the browser, and on Heroku. Have you any other idea?

Comment: Sounds like it is rooted in your (unified) development/deployment environment rather than Rails itself. I have never used Heroku, but it seems Heroku has its own encoding issue. Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612912/set-utf-8-as-default-string-encoding-in-heroku) of any help?

Comment: My heroku encoding is already in `UTF-8`, I've just checked it. So the problem is somewhere else. And this is the same on heroku instances and on localhost

Comment: @RémiDoolaeghe Have you checked the HTTP response header, particularly  `charset` in the Content-Type? It should be UTF-8. If not, it may be a problem in the config of your HTTP server (like Apache). How about `meta` tag of the HTML header for "Content-Type"? Also, have you checked the actual byte string you are seeing in the browser? The fact the output of `I18n.t` is in UTF-8 as expected indicates Rails is handling the translation correctly. So, a problem lies somewhere else, be it a browser, HTTP server, Heroku, or outermost interface in Rails…

Comment: The charset in the request is set to `UTF-8`. It's not in the response, but the `Content-Type` does not appear in the request response headers even if I manually set it. In the HTML meta, I have a `charset` set to `utf-8`. I have implemented a workaround which does the trick of fixing the encoding, but I'm not satisfied with it: I enforce the encoding in the request response header, and it works: `response.headers['X-Message'] = flash_message.encode('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8')`. So the problem does not come from the browser. It's somewhere between the translation and the request response building.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you open `fr.yml` file in utf-8 so that what you write is properly saved in utf-8. Probably this is the encoding that your browser is using.

You can go to your Linux console and look for your current configuration by looking the value of the LANG variable. I have for example `LANG="ca_ES.UTF-8"`. Maybe you also may check the encoding properties of your terminal window.

Also check in which encoding you're viewing your site. In Firefox for example, check the view/encoding option.

At the end you need to view the content in the same encoding that you persisted it.

Comment: My `fr.yml` is in UTF8, I can see it in RubyMine. My Linux LANG is in UTF8 too. I can't see anything that is not UTF8, but I must miss something.

Comment: Haves you checked which encoding is your browser using to view the page? Normally browsers use statistical determination to select the encoding so if they find iso specific characters they guess this is the correct encoding. So you must make sure that no ISO characters are rendered to the view

Comment: The problem seems to be before the browser receives the request. Directly in debug on back-end, I have encoding issues. But strangely, this doesn't happen in `rails console`

Comment: I may be that when you open the `rails console` Ruby guesses the correct encoding. When you open a debug console nobody guesses this and your default encoding is rendered, which is different from the encoding in the file.