# Unicode issues in rails console, but not in pry or irb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicode

I've got content `â\u0080\u0099` in some database columns I'm trying to find and replace with ActiveRecord, but Rails runtime and console appear to have trouble with that string, misinterpreting the first character. I see this in the Rails console, but not in pry or "plain" irb.

When I paste that string into the Rails console, it's converted to `\U+FFC3\U+FFA2\`, then ignored in the resulting string (see below).

I'd like to understand:

- what makes the Rails console different from irb/pry concerning encoding and how I may make it behave similarly regarding encoding
- how Rails was able to insert that data in the database in the first place (I'm having issues creating a unit test for this scenario for what I think are the same reasons as the console)

I'm on OS X Mojave using rbenv. I've tried [readline](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Add-Readline-support-to-Ruby-on-Mac-OS-X) and [environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44556239/2317829) solutions with no change.

**bin/rails console**

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 99194
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.2)
Cannot read termcap database;
using dumb terminal settings.
irb(main):001:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.5.3"
irb(main):002:0> Encoding::default_internal
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
irb(main):004:0> s = '\U+FFC3\U+FFA2\u0080\u0099'
=> "\\u0080\\u0099"
irb(main):005:0> s = "\U+FFC3\U+FFA2\u0080\u0099"
=> "\u0080\u0099"
```

**irb**

```
irb(main):018:0> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.5.3"
irb(main):019:0> s = 'â\u0080\u0099'
=> "â\\u0080\\u0099"
```

**pry**

```
$ gem list | grep pry
pry (0.12.2)
$ pry
[1] pry(main)> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.5.3"
[2] pry(main)> s = "â\u0080\u0099"
=> "â\u0080\u0099"
```

Etc.

- I noticed that `Encoding::default_internal` resolves to `#<Encoding:UTF-8>` in the Rails console, but to `nil` in irb and pry. Setting it to `nil` in the Rails console also did not solve my issue.
- Ultimately these strings display like `St. Patrickâs Day` in the browser

Comment: I still don't have answers to my bulleted questions, but uninstalling the Ruby and Rails versions, then unlinking and re-linking readline in brew, deleting my Gemfile.lock, then reinstalling those ruby and rails versions and bundling caused the Rails app and console to behave like irb and pry above.